# "Руки не доходят посмотреть" - так?

Tags: фразеология

Больше наблюдение, а не вопрос. Вдумался во фразу "Руки не доходят посмотреть". Это ж вынос мозга, особенно для иностранца))) А действительно, почему в крылатом выражении не доходят руки, а не ноги?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В любом случае человек использует для какого-то дела свои руки, они являются его основным инструментом-манипулятором. Об этой ситуации говорит известное выражение :
*Без тебя, как без рук*.
То, что руки сами по себе "ходить" не могут, не имеет значения. Слово *дошли/не дошли* может употребляться в переносном смысле, и оно употребляется в этом переносном смысле весьма активно.
*Дойти своим умом, дошел до ручки, сошел с ума, вышел из себя, прийти в экстаз, войти во вкус* и тд и тп...

Comment: > почему в крылатом выражении не доходят руки, а не ноги?

Потому что смотреть всё равно придётся глазами:)




Comment: Злата, я не увидела у Вас ни одного конструктивного ответа, а только какие-то издевки-наезды на спрашивающих. Или Вы даете ответы по существу, или воздержитесь от них вообще.  
С надеждой на понимание,  
администрация форума.